# Display all tooltips in chartjs

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

I'm using http://www.chartjs.org/ to create a simple line graph.

Now I want to show all tooltips. I do not want default on Hover behaviour. I am certain that at any moment I will not have more than 10-12 points on graph. So I want the tooltips to be always open.

If this is not possible with ChartJS, I'm open for opting for other library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible with [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) (a quick search did not reveal anything) but I think what you want is possible using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Here you can use the datalabels option:

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
```

Here is a [demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels). Does that help?

**EDIT:**

Another possibility for free could be [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com). For a demo have look [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php)! There is a pointLabels plugin which places labels on the plot at the data point locations. Should do the trick. :)

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title: 'Point Labels', 
      seriesDefaults: { 
        showMarker:false,
        pointLabels: { show:true } 
      }
  });
```

Cheers and good luck.

Comment: This helps definitely. And exactly what I was expecting from chartJS. But I was hoping to get a free solution. None the less if I do not get a better solution I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I guess you are developing a commercial software but only to note it here; highcharts is free for non-commercial software (a personal website, a school site or a non-profit organisation): http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts/#non-commercial

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more multiple static points please use annotations. Tooltips are just tips for a user when hovering instead of static information on different points in the graph.

I suggest using a wrapper on top of chartJS and using their annotation feature [https://apexcharts.com/docs/annotations/](http://%20https://apexcharts.com/docs/annotations/)